# How to integrate prisma with serverless framework aws-nodejs-typescript template

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, prisma, prisma2

I am building a serverless function using the serverless framework. However im having an issue with running it locally

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> open ''/.esbuild/.build/node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma'

**prisma/schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
    provider      = "prisma-client-js"
    binaryTargets = ["native", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}
```

**serverless.ts**

```
package: {
    individually: true,
    patterns: [
        "!node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-*",
        "node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-*",
        "!node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-*",
        "!node_modules/@prisma/engines/**",
    ],
},
```

steps:

```
npx prisma generate && npm install 

sls invoke local -f main
```

What am i doing wrong here?

**note**:

- attempting to follow this example: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/deployment-platforms/aws-lambda
- i am using the serverless aws-nodejs-typescirpt template which uses serverless-esbuild and not serverless-webpack

Comment: It looks like you're calling `npx prisma generate` before `npm install`. Don't you need `prisma` to be installed first through `npm install` before trying to call `prisma` commands?

Comment: I had a similar issue and wrote up my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985623/package-files-into-specific-folder-of-application-bundle-when-deploying-to-aws-l

Answer (score 5):

you can solve this by setting the location of Prisma Client. It works for both local and lambda.

**prisma/schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../src/generated/client"
}
```

```
npx prisma generate
```

**serverless.ts**

```
 package: {
    individually: true,
    patterns: [
      "src/generated/client/schema.prisma",
      "!src/generated/client/libquery_engine-*",
      "src/generated/client/libquery_engine-rhel-*",
      "!node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-*",
      "!node_modules/@prisma/engines/**",
    ],
  },
```

**some function**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "../generated/client";
```

**folder structure**

```
- src
  - functions
  - generated
- serverless.ts
- ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are attempting to import the `prisma.schema` file from your `node_modules` file, which is not where it normally goes. Where is your `prisma.schema` file located relative to the root of your project?

If it's not in `./prisma.schema`, you will need to configure its location by using this option:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema#prisma-schema-file-location