# Package files into specific folder of application bundle when deploying to AWS Lambda via Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework, prisma

### Context

I am using the [`aws-node-typescript`](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v3/aws-node-typescript) example of the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/). My goal is to integrate [Prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma) into it.

So far, I have:

1. Created the project locally using `serverless create`
2. Set up a PostgreSQL database on Railway
3. Installed `prisma`, ran `prisma init`, created a basic `User` model and ran `prisma migrate dev` successfully
4. Created a second `users` function by copying the existing `hello` function
5. Deployed the function using `serverless deploy`
6. Now in my function, when I instantiate `PrismaClient`, I get an internal server error and the function logs this error: `"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/src/functions/users/schema.prisma'"`

My project structure looks as follows:

```
.
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── prisma
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 20221006113352_init
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   └── migration_lock.toml
│   └── schema.prisma
├── serverless.ts
├── src
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── hello
│   │   │   ├── handler.ts
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   │   ├── mock.json
│   │   │   └── schema.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── users
│   │       ├── handler.ts
│   │       └── index.ts
│   └── libs
│       ├── api-gateway.ts
│       ├── handler-resolver.ts
│       └── lambda.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.paths.json
```

Also, here's the handler for the `users` function:
ts

```
import { formatJSONResponse } from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const users = async (event) => {

  console.log(`Instantiating PrismaClient inside handler ...`)
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()

  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello, ${event.queryStringParameters.name || 'there'} welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(users);
```

The problem arises because in order to instantiate `PrismaClient`, the `schema.prisma` file needs to be part of the application bundle. Specifically, it needs to be in `/var/task/src/functions/users/` as indicated by the error message.

I already adjusted the `package.patterns` option in my `serverless.ts` file to look as follows:

```
package: { individually: true, patterns: ["**/*.prisma"] },
```

### Question

This way, the bundle that's uploaded to AWS Lambda includes the `prisma` directory in its root, here's the `.serverless` folder after I ran `sls package` (I've unzipped `users.zip` here so that you can see its contents):

```
.
├── cloudformation-template-create-stack.json
├── cloudformation-template-update-stack.json
├── hello.zip
├── serverless-state.json
├── users
│   ├── prisma
│   │   └── schema.prisma
│   └── src
│       └── functions
│           └── users
│               ├── handler.js
│               └── handler.js.map
└── users.zip
```

I can also confirm that the deployed version of my AWS Lambda has the same folder structure.

How can I move the `users/prisma/schema.prisma` file into `users/src/functions/users` using the `patterns` in my `serverless.ts` file?

Comment: You could give `serverless-webpack-prisma` a try (https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-aws-lambda#deployment-using-serverless-webpack).

Comment: The `serverless-webpack-prisma`solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a (pretty ugly) solution. If anyone can think of a more elegant one, I'm still very open to it and happy to give you the points for a correct answer.

#### Solving the `"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/src/functions/users/schema.prisma'"` error

To solve this, I just took a very naive approach and manually *copied* over the `schema.prisma` file from the `prisma` directory into the `src/functions/users`. Here's the file structure I now had:

```
.
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── prisma
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 20221006113352_init
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   └── migration_lock.toml
│   └── schema.prisma
├── serverless.ts
├── src
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── hello
│   │   │   ├── handler.ts
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   │   ├── mock.json
│   │   │   └── schema.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── users
│   │       ├── schema.prisma
│   │       ├── handler.ts
│   │       └── index.ts
│   └── libs
│       ├── api-gateway.ts
│       ├── handler-resolver.ts
│       └── lambda.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.paths.json
```

This is obviously a horrible way to solve this, because I now have two Prisma schema files in different locations and have to make sure I always update the one in `src/functions/users/schema.prisma` after changing the original one in `prisma/schema.prisma` to keep them in sync.

Once I copied this file and redeployed, the `schema.prisma` file was in place in the right location in the AWS Lambda and the error went away and `PrismaClient` could be instantiated.

I then added a simple Prisma Client query into the handler:

```
const users = async (event) => {
  console.log(`Instantiating PrismaClient inside handler ...`)
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()

  const userCount = await prisma.user.count()
  console.log(`There are ${userCount} users in the database`)
  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello, ${event.queryStringParameters.name || 'there'} welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(users);
```

... and encountered a new error, this time, about the query engine:

```
Invalid `prisma.user.count()` invocation:


Query engine library for current platform \"rhel-openssl-1.0.x\" could not be found.
You incorrectly pinned it to rhel-openssl-1.0.x

This probably happens, because you built Prisma Client on a different platform.
(Prisma Client looked in \"/var/task/src/functions/users/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node\")

Searched Locations:

  /var/task/.prisma/client
  /Users/nikolasburk/prisma/talks/2022/serverless-conf-berlin/aws-node-typescript/node_modules/@prisma/client
  /var/task/src/functions
  /var/task/src/functions/users
  /var/task/prisma
  /tmp/prisma-engines
  /var/task/src/functions/users
  
  
  To solve this problem, add the platform \"rhel-openssl-1.0.x\" to the \"binaryTargets\" attribute in the \"generator\" block in the \"schema.prisma\" file:
generator client {
  provider      = \"prisma-client-js\"
  binaryTargets = [\"native\"]
  }

Then run \"prisma generate\" for your changes to take effect.
Read more about deploying Prisma Client: https://pris.ly/d/client-generator
```

#### Solving the `Query engine library for current platform \"rhel-openssl-1.0.x\" could not be found.` error

I'm familiar enough with Prisma to know that Prisma Client depends on a query engine binary that has to be built specifically for the platform Prisma Client will be running on. This can be configured via the [`binaryTargets`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#binarytargets-options) field on the `generator` block in my Prisma schema. The target for AWS Lamda is `rhel-openssl-1.0.x`.

So I adjusted the `schema.prisma` file (in both locations) accordingly:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}
```

After that, I ran `npx prisma generate` to update the generated Prisma Client in `node_modules`.

However, this hadn't resolved the error yet, the problem still was the Prisma Client couldn't find the query engine binary.

So I followed the same approach as for the `schema.prisma` file when it was missing:

1. I manually copied it into `src/functions/users` (this time from its location inside `node_modules/.prisma/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node`)
2. I added the new path to the `package.patterns` property in my `serverless.ts`:

   ```
   package: { 
     individually: true, 
     patterns: ["**/*.prisma", "**/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node"],
   },
   ```

After I redeployed and tested the function, another error occured:

```
Invalid `prisma.user.count()` invocation:


error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
-->  schema.prisma:11
| 
10 |   provider = \"postgresql\"
11 |   url      = env(\"DATABASE_URL\")
| 

Validation Error Count: 1
```

#### Solving the `Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.` error

This time, it was pretty straightforward and I went into the AWS Console at `https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/functions/aws-node-typescript-dev-users?tab=configure` and added a `DATABASE_URL` env var via the Console UI, pointing to my Postgres instance on Railway:

[image]

Comment: To solve the `Environment variable not found` problem, can consider using the [serverless-dotenv-plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv-plugin) to avoid manual input on `serverless.yml`

Answer (score 4):

We ran into the same issue recently. But our context is slightly different: the path to the `schema.prisma` file was `/var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma`.

We solved this issue by using Serverless [Package Configuration](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging#package-configuration).

`serverless.yml`

```yaml
service: 'your-service-name'

plugins:
 - serverless-esbuild

provider:
  # ...

package:
  include:
    - 'node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma' # <-------- this line
    - 'node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-*'
```

This way only the `src` folder containing the lambda functions and the `node_modules` folder containing these two Prisma files were packaged and uploaded to AWS.

Although the use of `serverless.package.include` and `serverless.package.exclude` is deprecated in favor of `serverless.package.patterns`, this was the only way to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct most forward way to do it :) Worked like a charm. My setup was I had my schema.prisma file in a directory for a docker image I built in order to trigger migrations from by invoking a lambda & there is no way to build a Docker image by reference the schema.prisma file if it was outside that directory where the Dockerfile lives

Answer (score 2):

I usually lurk but the answer above lead me to come up with a reasonably elegant solution I felt I should share for the next poor sap to come along and try to integrate serverless and prisma in Typescript (though, I bet this solution and process would work in other build systems).

I was using the example `aws-nodejs-typescript` template, which is plagued with a bug which required me to apply the fix [here](https://github.com/serverless/typescript/issues/27#issuecomment-779755994) by patching the local node_modules serverless package.

I then had to essentially walk through @nburk's answer to get myself up and running which is, as stated, inelegant.

In my travels trying to understand prisma's behavior, requirement of a platform-specific binary, and how to fix it, figured that if I could manually side-load the binary into the build folder post-compile I could get the serverless bundler to zip it up.

I came across the `'serverless-plugin-scripts'` [plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-scripts), which allows us to do exactly this via serverless lifecycle hooks.

I put this in my `serverless.ts`:
`plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-plugin-scripts'],`

I put the following in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'Error: no test specified' && exit 1",
    "postbuild": "yarn fix-scrape-scheduler",
    "fix-scrape-scheduler": "cp ../../node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma .esbuild/.build/src/functions/schedule-scrapes/. && cp ../../node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node .esbuild/.build/src/functions/schedule-scrapes/."
  },
```

and this also in my `serverless.ts`:

```
    scripts: {
      hooks: {
        'before:package:createDeploymentArtifacts': 'yarn run postbuild'
      }
    }
```

This causes the `'serverless-plugin-scripts'` plugin to call my `post-build` yarn script and fixup the `.build` folder that esbuild creates. I imagine that if your build system (such as webpack or something) creates the build dir under a different name (such as `lib`), this process could be modified accordingly.

I will have to create a yarn script to do this for each function that is individually packaged, however this is dynamic, precludes the need to keep multiple copies of `schema.prisma` in source, and copies the files from the dynamically generated `.prisma` folder in `node_modules`.

Note, I am using yarn workspaces here, so the location of your `node_modules` folder will vary based on your repo setup.

Also, I did run into this error `Please make sure your database server is running at` which was remedied by making sure the proper security groups were whitelisted outbound for the lambda function, and inbound for RDS. Also make sure to check your subnet ACLs and route-tables.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use **webpack** with the **copy-webpack-plugin** and change the structure of your application, put all handlers inside the **handlers folder**.

**Folders structure**:

```
.
├── handlers/
│   ├── hello.ts
│   └── ...
└── services/
    ├── hello.ts
    └── ...
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require("path");
// const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const { isLocal } = slsw.lib.webpack;

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  stats: "normal",
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  // externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  optimization: { concatenateModules: false },
  resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".ts"] },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "./prisma/schema.prisma",
          to: "handlers/schema.prisma",
        },
        {
          from: "./node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node",
          to: "handlers/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

If you need to run the **npx prisma generate** before assembling the package you can use the plugin **serverless-scriptable-plugin** (put before webpack):

```
plugins:
  - serverless-scriptable-plugin
  - serverless-webpack

custom:
  scriptable:
    hooks:
      before:package:createDeploymentArtifacts: npx prisma generate
  webpack:
    includeModules: false
```

Dependences:

```
npm install -D webpack serverless-webpack webpack-node-externals copy-webpack-plugin serverless-scriptable-plugin
```